# How to do Product Complex Filtering in SQL / Net Core

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, filter

I have a Net Core 2.2 Web Application , SQL Server 2017, Linq, Entity Core, SQLQuery FromSql

I need to do complex filters for products like in e-commerce websites where you can Filter laptops by Attributes (Brands: Dell, HP, Memory: 2 GB, 4 GB)

Example: **(Dell Brand or HP Brand ) and (Size S or Size XL).**

I have Problems when I try to Display Attribute and Values with the Number of the products (**Count**) after multiple attribute selection (ex:  Dell ( 4 items ) after selecting 2 GB or 4 GB)

Attributes / Filters:

```
Brand
- Dell (2 items)
- HP (3)

Memory
- 2 GB (2)
- 4 GB(3)

Display
- 17 inch (1)
- 19 inch ( 2)
```

Because can't achieve this in LINQ it must be done using string SQLQuery FromSql

SQL Database Structure :

```
**Products** ( Ex: Laptop 1, Laptop 2 ) 
- ProductID

**Attributes** ( Ex: Memory, Brand ) 
- AttributeID

**AttributeValues** ( Ex: 2 Gb, Dell )
- AttributeValueID
- AttributeID ( foreign key )

**ProductAttributes** 
-ProductAttibuteID
-ProductID ( foreign key )
-AttributeID (  foreign key )
-AttributeValueID ( foreign key )
```

I have Tried something, but is not working doesn't count well :

```
 public class Filter
    {
        public int AtributeID { get; set; }
        public int ?AtributeValueID { get; set; }       
    }


// Filters - list with selected attributes ( AtributeID ,AtributeValueID )

string SQLQuery = "SELECT AtributeValueID,Title,Importance,AtributeID , (select count (*) from Products p where p.ProductCategoryID ={0}";

foreach (var filtersGroup in Filters.GroupBy(p => p.AtributeID))
{
    int atributeID = filtersGroup.Key;
    var atributeValues = filtersGroup.Select(p => p.AtributeValueID).ToList();

    SQLQuery += "and exists ( select 1 from ProductAtributes pa where pa.ProductID=p.ProductID and  ((av.AtributeID = " + atributeID + " and pa.AtributeValueID = av.AtributeValueID) ";

    foreach (var atributeValueID in atributeValues)
    {
        SQLQuery += " or pa.AtributeValueID=" + atributeValueID;
    }

    SQLQuery += "))";
}

SQLQuery += ") as Count";

SQLQuery += " FROM AtributeValues av ";


var queryAtributesValuesResult = context.Query<AtributeValueDTO>()
.FromSql(SQLQuery)
.AsNoTracking()
.ToList();

Executed DbCommand (1,203ms)
SELECT AtributeValueID,Title,Importance,AtributeID, 
(
    select count (*) from Products p where 
        exists 
        ( 
            select 1 from ProductAtributes pa where pa.ProductID=p.ProductID  
                                                    and ((av.AtributeID = 15 and pa.AtributeValueID = av.AtributeValueID) or pa.AtributeValueID=130)        
        )            
        and exists 
        ( 
            select 1 from ProductAtributes pa where pa.ProductID=p.ProductID 
                                                    and  ((av.AtributeID = 27 and pa.AtributeValueID = av.AtributeValueID) or pa.AtributeValueID=273 or pa.AtributeValueID=325)
        )      
)as Count 
FROM AtributeValues av
```

Comment: LINQ is ideal for constructing complex condition queries on the fly. Show your entities.

Comment: I Use SQL Server 2017 . The Server is in Azure . Yes, The context is Entity Core Framework. Yes I understood that Linq can't be used in this situation and this is the reason why our focus is to write a query, a view, or whatever but in SQL

Comment: The problem is solved? If not, show your entities in C#, I'll give a solution in LINQ.

Comment: No, it is not resolved . The Entities are the same as database structure: Products ( Ex: Laptop 1, Laptop 2 ) 
- ProductID

**Attributes** ( Ex: Memory, Brand ) 
- AttributeID

AttributeValues ( Ex: 2 Gb, Dell )
- AttributeValueID
- AttributeID ( foreign key )

**ProductAttributes** 
-ProductAttibuteID
-ProductID ( foreign key )
-AttributeID (  foreign key )
-AttributeValueID ( foreign key )

Answer (score 0):

Your ProductAtributes contains all columns from other tables, try this to get products
which have attr15=val130 and attr27 = 273 or 325

```
select pa1.*, pa2.AtributeID, pa2.AtributeValueID
  , dense_rank() over (order by id pa1.ProductId) 
    + dense_rank() over (order by id pa1.ProductId desc) - 1 as productCount
from ProductAtributes pa1 
join ProductAtributes pa2 on pa1.ProductId = pa2.ProductId
  and pa1.AtributeID = 15 and pa1.AtributeValueID in (130) 
  and pa2.AtributeID = 27 and pa2.AtributeValueID in (273, 325)
```

Generally you need as many JOINs as many attributes requested to restore a virtual "Product with the set of attributes" relation and then to apply attribute predicates as needed.

**EDIT** Added an analytic function based expression to count products. Sql server doesn't support `DISTINCT` option in [analytic `COUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) . So I use `DENSE_RANK` but it does not supprort window frame needed, `rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following`, and I use sum of 2 default frames, rows before and after `pa1.ProductId`.

Comment: Thank's . How can I count the products asociated to a filter in the same time ? My Proposed Database Structure it is ok ? Should I restructure it ? use another temporary tables to restructure Data in a more convenient way to get more performance ? or maybe materialised views or Json Data in SQL ? Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: You'll find a lot of pros and contras googling "eav db design". My rule of thumb is don't go EAV path till it's absolutely inevitable. See update regarding count.